# How can I display only incorrect answers and keep same table layout

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Below I have 4 database tables, Session, Question, Answer and Option_Type.

**Session Table:**

```
SessionId  SessionName
1          AAA
```

**Question Table:**

```
SessionId   QuestionId  QuestionContent       OptionId
1           1           What is 1+1 and 4+4   2
1           2           Does 2+2 = 4          26
1           3           What is 3+3 and 5+5   3
```

**Answer Table:**

```
AnswerId  SessionId QuestionId  Answer
1         1         1           B
2         1         1           C
3         1         2           Yes
4         1         3           A
5         1         3           C
```

**Option_Type**

```
OptionId OptionType
1        A-C
2        A-D
3        A-E
4        A-F

.... goes up to 24 where it goes up to A-Z

25       True or False
26       Yes or No
```

Now in a jsfiddle here I have created a demo html table which you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WHUkh/6/)

Now if you have a good look at the html table, you will realise that what I am trying to do is display the incorrect answers under the "Incorrect Answer" column.

So for example for Question 1:

- Option type is A-D
- Correct Answer is B, C
- So Incorrect answers that should be dislayed in table is A and D

So my question is that how in my php script can I select the option_type for a question, display all of the possible answers and remove the correct answers, displaying only the incorrect answers? The layout of the table must be the same as the layout in the jsfiddle.

Below is the table output in the php script. At the moment it is displaying similar table as in jsfiddle except difference is that it is outputting correct answers, not incorrect answers.

```
   $query = "SELECT q.SessionId, s.SessionName, q.QuestionId, q.QuestionContent, an.Answer, q.QuestionMarks 
   FROM Session s 
   INNER JOIN Question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
   JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId AND an.SessionId = q.SessionId
   WHERE s.SessionName = ?
   ORDER BY q.QuestionId, an.Answer
   ";

   // prepare query
   $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
   // You only need to call bind_param once
   $stmt->bind_param("s", $assessment);
   // execute query
   $stmt->execute(); 


       // This will hold the search results
    $searchQuestionId = array();
    $searchQuestionContent = array();
    $searchAnswer = array();
    $searchMarks = array();

    // Fetch the results into an array

   // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
   $stmt->bind_result($dbSessionId, $dbSessionName, $dbQuestionId, $dbQuestionContent, $dbAnswer, $dbQuestionMarks);
      while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $searchQuestionId[] = $dbQuestionId;
        $searchQuestionContent[] = $dbQuestionContent;
        $searchAnswer[] = $dbAnswer;
        $searchMarks[] = $dbQuestionMarks;
      } 

?>      

</head>

<body>

<form id="QandA" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">

<?php 

echo "<table border='1' id='markstbl'>
      <tr>
      <th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
      <th class='questionth'>Question</th>
      <th class='answerth'>Incorrect Answer</th>
      <th class='answermarksth'>Penalty per Incorrect Answer</th>
      </tr>\n";
$previous_question_id = null;
$rowspans = array_count_values($searchQuestionId);
foreach ($searchQuestionContent as $key=>$question) {

    // removed logic, not necessary to set empty strings if you're skipping them

    echo '<tr class="questiontd">'.PHP_EOL;

    if ($previous_question_id != $searchQuestionId[$key]) {
        echo '<td class="questionnumtd" name="numQuestion" rowspan="'.$rowspans[$searchQuestionId[$key]].'">'.htmlspecialchars($searchQuestionId[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td class="questioncontenttd" rowspan="'.$rowspans[$searchQuestionId[$key]].'">'.htmlspecialchars($question).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo '<td class="answertd" name="answers[]">';
    echo $searchAnswer[$key];
    echo '</td>' ;
    echo '<td class="answermarkstd"><input class="individualMarks" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" /></td>' . PHP_EOL;

    // moved this to the end
    if ($previous_question_id != $searchQuestionId[$key]) {
        $previous_question_id = $searchQuestionId[$key];
    }
}
        echo '</tr>';
        echo "</table>" . PHP_EOL;

        ?>

</form>
```

At the moment the code above is showing the correct answers under the "Incorrect Answers" column, not the incorrect answers.

Comment: Does your "Answer Table" also include the incorrect choices?  Your sample data only shows the correct answers in there.  I find the "Option Type" to be a strange approach as well.

Comment: @AllInOne The answer table only shows correct answers. I am open to any approach, it is just that I want it to be able to display the correct possible answers per question and then only display the incorrect answers, not the correct answers

Comment: How are you building the question set?  Where do the incorrect answer choices come from when the test is presented?

Comment: @AllInOne I simply just list the options for a question, e.g A B C D, then I select the correct answers from those options, the correct answers will be displayed in the "Answer" table. So this is why I was thinking that the other options (the other answers which were not selected as the correct answer) can be displayed as the incorrect answers.

Comment: is this a homework assignment? I swear this is like the third time I've seen almost identical sample data.

Comment: @invertedSpear Team Project, on final part of project where we need to to give marks to penalize for every wrong answer given